# Ошибка синтакса в stored procedure в условии с select found_rows()

Tags: mysql, sql

В словесной игре типа Эрудита для Android -

[image: скриншот]

данные об играх хранятся в таблице **games**:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gid      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| player2  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| stamp1   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stamp2   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| letters1 | varchar(7)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| letters2 | varchar(7)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| letters  | varchar(116) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| board    | varchar(225) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| style    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

где колонки **player1** и **player2** содержат номера (в смысле **uid**) противников в игре.

А колонки **stamp1** и **stamp2** это timestamps их последних ходов.

Я пытаюсь написать [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-views.html), которая получает в качестве аргумента **uid** игрока - и либо присоединяется к уже существующей игре с 1 другим игроком, либо создает новую игру.

Перед этим проверяется одно спецусловие: если уже есть новая игра, но игрок **uid** еще не сделал 1й ход - то прислать ему **gid** этой игры (вместо создания еще одной новой).

```
delimiter $$$

drop procedure if exists find_game;
create procedure find_game(IN uid integer,
                           IN letters1 varchar(7),
                           IN letters2 varchar(7),
                           IN letters varchar(116),
                           OUT gid integer)
begin
        start transaction;

        /* спецусловие: может новая игра уже создана и игроку надо просто сделать ход? */
        select gid into @gid from games
        where (player1 = uid and stamp1 = 0) 
        or (player2 = uid and stamp2 = 0) limit 1;

        IF select found_rows() = 0 THEN
                /* попытка найти игру с одним свободным местом */
                select gid into @gid from games
                where (player1 != uid and stamp1 > 0 
                and player2 is null) limit 1;

                IF select found_rows() > 0 THEN
                        update games set player2 = uid where gid = @gid;
                ELSE
                        /* создание новой игры с player1 = uid и stamp1 = 0*/
                        insert into games (created, player1, stamp1, stamp2, letters1, letters2, letters, board, style)
                        values (unix_timestamp(), @uid, 0, 0, letters1, letters2, letters, space(225), 1);

                        select last_insert_id() into @gid;
                END IF;
        END IF;

        commit;
end
$$$
```

К сожалению, MySQL 5.6 выдает синтактическую ошибку:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 
'select found_rows() = 0 THEN

                select gid into @g' at line 13
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Я последовал совету Майка (спасибо!) и убрал `select` из `IF select found_rows()`.

Кроме того, я заменил `uid` на `@uid` (не пойму, нужна там *собака* или нет):

```
delimiter $$$

drop procedure if exists find_game;
create procedure find_game(IN uid integer,
                           IN letters1 varchar(7),
                           IN letters2 varchar(7),
                           IN letters varchar(116),
                           OUT gid integer)
begin
        start transaction;

        select gid into @gid from games
        where (player1 = @uid and stamp1 = 0) 
        or (player2 = @uid and stamp2 = 0) limit 1;

        IF found_rows() = 0 THEN
                select gid into @gid from games
                where (player1 != @uid and stamp1 > 0 
                and player2 is null) limit 1;

                IF found_rows() > 0 THEN
                        update games set player2 = @uid where gid = @gid;
                ELSE
                        insert into games (created, player1, stamp1, stamp2, letters1, letters2, letters, board, style)
                        values (unix_timestamp(), uid, 0, 0, letters1, letters2, letters, space(225), 1);

                        select last_insert_id() into @gid;
                END IF;
        END IF;

        commit;
end
$$$
```

Но теперь я получаю `NULL` в качестве результата:

```
mysql> call find_game(1, "xxxxxxx", "yyyyyyy", "zzz", @gid);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select @gid;
+------+
| @gid |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

И это странно, потому что при вызове первой `select`-команды вручную я получаю не-нулевые значения:

```
mysql> select gid from games where (player1 = 1 and stamp1 = 0) or (player2 = 1 and stamp2 = 0);
+-----+
| gid |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: может без select: `IF  found_rows() > 0 THEN`

Comment: Спасибо (+1) похоже `select` и вправду не нужен, но теперь я почему-то получаю `NULL` (см. обновленный вопрос).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В предложении `IF found_rows() > 0 THEN` select после слова IF не нужен.
2. Внутри процедуры вы используете переменную `@gid` и это не то же самое, что выходной параметр `gid out integer`. Вам в конце процедуры надо сделать:

   ```
   select @gid into gid;
   ```

Но лучше переименовать входной параметр что бы не было коллизий в строке `select gid into @gid from games`. Данная строка скорее всего делает совершенно не то, что вы ожидаете, она не выбирает значение колонки `gid` из таблицы `games`, а выбирает значение параметра `gid` в переменную, а значение из таблицы вообще не использует.

Вам вообще надо отказаться от использования `@` - они предназначены для совершенно других переменных, никакого отношения к параметрам не имеющих. Назовите все свои параметры так, что бы они точно не конфликтовали с именами колонок в таблицах. Все выражения должны быть похожи на `select gid into p_gid from games`, при условии, что параметр вы назовете `p_gid`.